# Rails 4 Error with every command "`load': no implicit conversion of nil into String" (Mac OS X 10.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos

I've just installed a fresh Ruby on Rails dev stack on my new Macbook, which runs Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

Here is my stack:

- Xcode command line tools
- Homebrew
- Rbenv
- Bundler
- Ruby 2.1.0
- Rails 4.1.1

I ran `rails new test_app` to generate a first test app.
This command successfully completed, but since it, every Rails command I try in my CLI returns this kind of error message:

```
$ test_app > bin/rails server

/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Documents/[PERSONNEL]/dev/test_app/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Same error while trying to start a console:

```
$ test_app > bin/rails c

/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The `bin/rake` are working partially (I can use `bin/rake routes` but migrations are not working).

My last try was to install **XCode**, but it didn't solve it.

---

**UPDATE**: the command `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin` as mentioned bellow solve the problem for project, but needed to be executed on every new problem.
The problem seems to be deeper.

Answer (score 6):

OK I found solution.

I've cleaned my mac too. and I got same error.

rails_root/bin folder is not there?

Try below

`bundle exec rake rails:update:bin`

Comment: Don't know how you manage to find it out, but it works, and now all my new projects work again! Thx!

Comment: I still have a problem with my migrations whatever, which stay down. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Short exploration follows below.

First of all, I have `[]` in the root path for my application. The error during `rails s` command

```
psylone@wizard:~/ruby-rails[code]/context$ rails s
/home/psylone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:30:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

is in `spring gem` here: https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/lib/spring/client/rails.rb#L27

That's because if `Dir.glob` contains `[]` in the path argument the result will be an empty array. So it's necessary to escape `[]` in the path argument for `Dir.glob` method. I think about something like this:

```
# Instead of line 27 in spring/client/rails.rb
require 'shellwords'
path = Shellwords.escape(Spring.application_root_path) << "/{bin,script}/rails"
load path
```

After this fix I've found `rails s` command works fine. But `rails c` command still causes an error. Probably the answer has the same nature.

So, **the simplest way to avoid this error - rename the root path for your application (without `[]` characters)**.

Comment: Thanks for investigating! I don't have the problem any more, so I can't validate your solution. Really appreciate your share however. :)