# Deploy to EC2 with Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubber

I have been having issues trying to deploy with rubber

in the **Terminal**

```
rubber vulcanize complete_passenger_postgresql
```

and in my **rubber.yml**

```
# REQUIRED: The name of your application
app_name: app-name

# REQUIRED: The system user to run your app servers as
app_user: app

# REQUIRED: Notification emails (e.g. monit) get sent to this address
#
admin_email: "root@#{full_host}"

# OPTIONAL: If not set, you won't be able to access web_tools
# server (graphite, graylog, monit status, haproxy status, etc)
# web_tools_user: admin
# web_tools_password: sekret

# REQUIRED: The timezone the server should be in
timezone: US/Eastern

# REQUIRED: the domain all the instances should be associated with
#
domain: foo.com

# OPTIONAL: See rubber-dns.yml for dns configuration
# This lets rubber update a dynamic dns service with the instance alias
# and ip when they are created.  It also allows setting up arbitrary
# dns records (CNAME, MX, Round Robin DNS, etc)

# OPTIONAL: Additional rubber file to pull config from if it exists.  This file will
# also be pushed to remote host at Rubber.root/config/rubber/rubber-secret.yml
#
rubber_secret: "#{File.expand_path('~') + '/.ec2' + (Rubber.env == 'production' ? '' : '_dev') + '/rubber-secret.yml' rescue 'rubber-secret.yml'}"

# OPTIONAL: Encryption key that was used to obfuscate the contents of rubber-secret.yml with "rubber util:obfuscation" 
# Not that much better when stored in here, but you could use a ruby snippet in here to fetch it from a key server or something
#
# rubber_secret_key: "XXXyyy=="

# REQUIRED All known cloud providers with the settings needed to configure them
# There's only one working cloud provider right now - Amazon Web Services
# To implement another, clone lib/rubber/cloud/aws.rb or make the fog provider 
# work in a generic fashion
#
cloud_providers:
  aws:
    # REQUIRED The AWS region that you want to use.
    #
    # Options include
    # ap-northeast-1 # Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Region
    # ap-southeast-1 # Asia Pacific (Singapore) Region
    # ap-southeast-2 # Asia Pacific (Sydney) Region
    # eu-west-1      # EU (Ireland) Region
    # sa-east-1      # South America (Sao Paulo) Region
    # us-east-1      # US East (Northern Virginia) Region
    # us-west-1      # US West (Northern California) Region
    # us-west-2      # US West (Oregon) Region
    #
    region: us-east-1

    # REQUIRED The amazon keys and account ID (digits only, no dashes) used to access the AWS API
    #
    access_key: XXX
    secret_access_key: YYY
    account: ZZZ #entered in

    # REQUIRED:  The name of the amazon keypair and location of its private key
    #
    # NOTE: for some reason Capistrano requires you to have both the public and
    # the private key in the same folder, the public key should have the
    # extension ".pub".  The easiest way to get your hand on this is to create the
    # public key from the private key: ssh-keygen -y -f gsg-keypair > gsg-keypair.pub
    #
    key_name: guy
    key_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/*' + cloud_providers.aws.key_name].first}"

    # OPTIONAL: Needed for bundling a running instance using rubber:bundle
    #
    # pk_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/pk-*'].first}"
    # cert_file: "#{Dir[(File.expand_path('~') rescue '/root') + '/.ec2/cert-*'].first}"
    # image_bucket: "#{app_name}-images"

    # OPTIONAL: Needed for backing up database to s3
    # backup_bucket: "#{app_name}-backups"

    # REQUIRED: the ami and instance type for creating instances
    # The Ubuntu images at http://alestic.com/ work well
    # Ubuntu 14.04.1 Trusty instance-store 64-bit: ami-92f569fa
    #
    # m1.small or m1.large or m1.xlarge
    image_type: m3.medium
    image_id: ami-1ecae776

    # OPTIONAL: Provide fog-specific options directly.  This should only be used if you need a special setting that
    # Rubber does not directly expose.  Since these settings will be passed directly through to fog, we can't make any
    # guarantee about how they work (if fog renames an attribute, e.g., your config will break).  Please see the fog
    # source code for the option names.
    # fog_options:
      # EBS I/O optimized instance
      # EBS-optimized instances deliver dedicated throughput between Amazon EC2 and Amazon EBS, with options
      # between 500 Mbps and 1000 Mbps depending on the instance type used.
      # Read more and make sure that your image_type supports ebs_optimized function at: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
      # ebs_optimized: false

    # OPTIONAL: EC2 spot instance request support.
    #
    # Enables the creation of spot instance requests.  Rubber will wait synchronously until the request is fulfilled,
    # at which point it will begin initializing the instance, unless spot_instance_request_timeout is set.
    # spot_instance: true
    #
    # The maximum price you would like to pay for your spot instance.
    # spot_price: "0.085"
    #
    # If a spot instance request can't be fulfilled in 3 minutes, fallback to on-demand instance creation.  If not set,
    # the default is infinite.
    # spot_instance_request_timeout: 180

  # digital_ocean:
    # REQUIRED: The Digital Ocean region that you want to use.
    #
    # Options include
    # New York 1
    # Amsterdam 1
    # San Francisco 1
    # New York 2
    # Amsterdam 2
    # Singapore 1
    #
    # These change often.  Check https://www.digitalocean.com/droplets/new for the most up to date options.
    # Default to New York 2 since this is the only region that currently supports private networking
    # region: New York 2

    # REQUIRED: The image name and type for creating instances.
    # image_id: Ubuntu 14.04 x64
    # image_type: 512MB

    # Optionally enable private networking for your instances.
    # This is currently only supported in New York 2.
    # private_networking: true

  # Use an alternate cloud provider supported by fog.  This doesn't fully work
  # yet due to differences in providers within fog, but gives you a starting
  # point for contributing a new provider to rubber.  See rubber/lib/rubber/cloud(.rb)
  # fog:
  #   credentials:
  #     provider: rackspace
  #     rackspace_api_key: 'XXX'
  #     rackspace_username: 'YYY'
  #   image_type: 123
  #   image_id: 123

# REQUIRED the cloud provider to use
#
cloud_provider: aws

# OPTIONAL: Where to store instance data.
#
# Allowed forms are:
# filesystem: "file:#{Rubber.root}/config/rubber/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"
# cloud storage (s3): "storage:#{cloud_providers.aws.backup_bucket}/RubberInstances_#{app_name}/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"
# cloud table (simpledb): "table:RubberInstances_#{app_name}_#{Rubber.env}"
#
# If you need to port between forms, load the rails console then:
# Rubber.instances.save(location)
# where location is one of the allowed forms for this variable
#
# instance_storage: "file:#{Rubber.root}/config/rubber/instance-#{Rubber.env}.yml"

# OPTIONAL: Where to store a backup of the instance data
#
# This is most useful when using a remote store in case you end up
# wiping the single copy of your instance data.  When using the file
# store, the instance file is typically under version control with
# your project code, so that provides some safety.
#
# instance_storage_backup: "storage:#{cloud_providers.aws.backup_bucket}/RubberInstances_#{app_name}/instance-#{Rubber.env}-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')}.yml"

# OPTIONAL: Default ports for security groups
web_port: 80
web_ssl_port: 443
web_tools_port: 8080
web_tools_ssl_port: 8443

# OPTIONAL: Define security groups
# Each security group is a name associated with a sequence of maps where the
# keys are the parameters to the ec2 AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress API
# source_security_group_name, source_security_group_owner_id
# ip_protocol, from_port, to_port, cidr_ip
# If you want to use a source_group outside of this project, add "external_group: true"
# to prevent group_isolation from mangling its name, e.g.  to give access to graphite
# server to other projects
#
# security_groups:
#   graphite_server:
#     description: The graphite_server security group to allow projects to send graphite data
#     rules:
#       - source_group_name: yourappname_production_collectd
#         source_group_account: 123456
#         external_group: true
#         protocol: tcp
#         from_port: "#{graphite_server_port}"
#         to_port: "#{graphite_server_port}"
#
security_groups:
  default:
    description: The default security group
    rules:
      - source_group_name: default
        source_group_account: "#{cloud_providers.aws.account}"
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: 22
        to_port: 22
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
  web:
    description: "To open up port #{web_port}/#{web_ssl_port} for http server on web role"
    rules:
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_ssl_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_ssl_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
  web_tools:
    description: "To open up port #{web_tools_port}/#{web_tools_ssl_port} for internal/tools http server"
    rules:
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_tools_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_tools_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]
      - protocol: tcp
        from_port: "#{web_tools_ssl_port}"
        to_port: "#{web_tools_ssl_port}"
        source_ips: [0.0.0.0/0]

# OPTIONAL: The default security groups to create instances with
assigned_security_groups: [default]
roles:
  web:
    assigned_security_groups: [web]
  web_tools:
    assigned_security_groups: [web_tools]

# OPTIONAL: Automatically create security groups for each host and role
# EC2 Classic doesn't allow one to change what groups an instance belongs to after
# creation, so it's good to have some empty ones predefined.  EC2 with VPC, however,
# does allow changing security groups after instance creation and allows far fewer
# security groups per instance, so you shouldn't enable this setting if using VPC.
auto_security_groups: false

# OPTIONAL: Automatically isolate security groups for each appname/environment
# by mangling their names to be appname_env_groupname
# This makes it safer to have staging and production coexist on the same EC2
# account, or even multiple apps.  NB: due to the security group limits per instance
# in EC2 with VPCs, this option should only be enabled if you're using EC2 Classic.
isolate_security_groups: false

# OPTIONAL: Prompts one to sync security group rules when the ones in amazon
# differ from those in rubber
prompt_for_security_group_sync: false

# OPTIONAL: A list of CIDR address blocks that represent private networks for your cluster.
# Set this to open up wide access to hosts in your network.  Consequently, setting the CIDR block
# to anything other than a private, unroutable block would be a massive security hole.
private_networks: [10.0.0.0/8]

# OPTIONAL: The packages to install on all instances
# You can install a specific version of a package by using a sub-array of pkg, version
# For example, packages: [[rake, 0.7.1], irb]
packages: [postfix, build-essential, git-core, libxslt-dev, ntp]

# OPTIONAL: The package manager mirror to use for installation of primary packages (i.e., those not explicitly
# sourced from a different repository).  If not specified, whatever mirror configured by your server image
# will be used.
#
# Note that Ubuntu has a special URL that can be used to auto-select the mirror based upon geoip.  To use
# it, specify 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt' as the value.
# package_manager_mirror: 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt'

# OPTIONAL: The command used to identify your particular OS version.  This will be used for configurations
# in Rubber templates that are parameterized by OS version (e.g., package lists).  If not specified, Ubuntu
# will be assumed.
os_version_cmd: 'lsb_release -sr'

# OPTIONAL: gem sources to setup for rubygems
# gemsources: ["https://rubygems.org"]

# OPTIONAL: The gems to install on all instances
# You can install a specific version of a gem by using a sub-array of gem, version
# For example, gem: [[rails, 2.2.2], open4, aws-s3]
gems: [open4, aws-s3, bundler, [rubber, "#{Rubber.version}"]]

# OPTIONAL: A string prepended to shell command strings that cause multi
# statement shell commands to fail fast.  You may need to comment this out
# on some platforms, but it works for me on linux/osx with a bash shell
#
stop_on_error_cmd: "function error_exit { exit 99; }; trap error_exit ERR"

# OPTIONAL: The default set of roles to use when creating a staging instance
# with "cap rubber:create_staging".  By default this uses all the known roles,
# excluding slave roles, but this is not always desired for staging, so you can
# specify a different set here
#
# staging_roles: "web,app,db:primary=true"
# Auto detect staging roles
staging_roles: "#{known_roles.reject {|r| r =~ /slave/ || r =~ /^db$/ }.join(',')}"

# OPTIONAL: Lets one assign amazon elastic IPs (static IPs) to your instances
#           You should typically set this on the role/host level rather than
#           globally , unless you really do want all instances to have a
#           static IP
#
# use_static_ip: true

# OPTIONAL: Specifies an instance to be created in the given availability zone
#           Availability zones are sepcified by amazon to be somewhat isolated
#           from each other so that hardware failures in one zone shouldn't
#           affect instances in another.  As such, it is good to specify these
#           for instances that need to be redundant to reduce your chance of
#           downtime. You should typically set this on the role/host level
#           rather than globally.  Use cap rubber:describe_zones to see the list
#           of zones
# availability_zone: us-east-1a

# OPTIONAL: If you want to use Elastic Block Store (EBS) persistent
# volumes, add them to host specific overrides and they will get created
# and assigned to the instance.  On initial creation, the volume will get
# attached _and_ formatted, but if your host disappears and you recreate
# it, the volume will only get remounted thereby preserving your data
#
# hosts:
#   production15:
#     availability_zone: us-east-1b
#     volumes:
#       - size: 100 # size of vol in GBs
#         zone: us-east-1b # zone to create volume in, needs to match host's zone
#         device: /dev/sdh # OS device to attach volume to
#         mount: /mnt/postgresql # The directory to mount this volume to
#         filesystem: ext4 # the filesystem to create on volume
#
#         # OPTIONAL: Provide fog-specific options directly.  This should only be used if you need a special setting that
#         # Rubber does not directly expose.  Since these settings will be passed directly through to fog, we can't make any
#         # guarantee about how they work (if fog renames an attribute, e.g., your config will break).  Please see the fog
#         # source code for the option names.
#         fog_options:
#           type: gp2 # type of volume, standard (EBS magnetic), io1 (provisioned IOPS - SSD), or gp2 (general purpose - SSD).
#           iops: 500 # The number of I/O operations per second (IOPS) that the volume supports.
#                     # Required when the volume type is io1; not used with non-provisioned IOPS volumes.
#       - size: 10
#         zone: us-east-1a
#         device: /dev/sdi
#         mount: /mnt/logs
#         filesystem: ext4
#         fog_options:
#           type: io1
#           iops: 500
#
#       # volumes without mount/filesystem can be used in raid arrays
#
#       - size: 50
#         zone: us-east-1a
#         device: /dev/sdx
#         fog_options:
#           type: gp2
#           iops: 500
#       - size: 50
#         zone: us-east-1a
#         device: /dev/sdy
#         fog_options:
#           type: gp2
#           iops: 500
#
#    # Use some ephemeral volumes for raid array
#    local_volumes:
#      - partition_device: /dev/sdb
#        zero: false # zeros out disk for improved performance
#      - partition_device: /dev/sdc
#        zero: false # zeros out disk for improved performance
#
#     # for raid array, you'll need to add mdadm to packages.  Likewise,
#     # xfsprogs is needed for xfs filesystem support
#     #
#     packages: [xfsprogs, mdadm]
#     raid_volumes:
#       - device: /dev/md0 # OS device to to create raid array on
#         mount: /mnt/fast # The directory to mount this array to
#         mount_opts: 'nobootwait' # Recent Ubuntu versions require this flag or SSH will not start on reboot
#         filesystem: xfs # the filesystem to create on array
#         filesystem_opts: -f # the filesystem opts in mkfs
#         raid_level: 0 # the raid level to use for the array
#         # if you're using Ubuntu 11.x or later (Natty, Oneiric, Precise, etc)
#         # you will want to specify the source devices in their /dev/xvd format
#         # see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/684875 for
#         # more information.
#         # NOTE: Only make this change for raid source_devices, NOT generic
#         # volume commands above.
#         source_devices: [/dev/sdx, /dev/sdy] # the source EBS devices we are creating raid array from (Ubuntu Lucid or older)
#         source_devices: [/dev/xvdx, /dev/xvdy] # the source EBS devices we are creating raid array from (Ubuntu Natty or newer)
#
#     # for LVM volumes, you'll need to add lvm2 to packages.  Likewise,
#     # xfsprogs is needed for xfs filesystem support
#     packages: [xfsprogs, lvm2]
#     lvm_volume_groups:
#       - name: vg # The volume group name
#         physical_volumes: [/dev/sdx, /dev/sdy] # Devices used for LVM group (you can use just one, but you can't stripe then)
#         extent_size: 32 # Size of the volume extent in MB
#         volumes:
#           - name: lv # Name of the logical volume
#             size: 999.9 # Size of volume in GB (slightly less than sum of all physical volumes because LVM reserves some space)
#             stripes: 2 # Count of stripes for volume
#             filesystem: xfs # The filesystem to create on the logical volume
#             filesystem_opts: -f # the filesystem opts in mkfs
#             mount: /mnt/large_work_dir # The directory to mount this LVM volume to

# OPTIONAL: You can also define your own variables here for use when
# transforming config files, and they will be available in your config
# templates as  <%%= rubber_env.var_name %>
#
# var_name: var_value

# All variables can also be overridden on the role, environment and/or host level by creating
# a sub level to the config under roles, environments and hosts.  The precedence is host, environment, role
# e.g. to install mysql only on db role, and awstats only on web01:

# OPTIONAL: Role specific overrides
# roles:
#   somerole:
#     packages: []
#   somerole2:
#     myconfig: someval

# OPTIONAL: Environment specific overrides
# environments:
#   staging:
#     myconfig: otherval
#   production:
#     myconfig: val

# OPTIONAL: Host specific overrides
# hosts:
#   somehost:
#     packages: []
```

And doing a

```
cap rubber:create
```

I get the error after:

```
* executing `rubber:setup_local_aliases'
/home/casekey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rubber-2.16.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/setup.rb:192:in `block (3 levels) in load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

**setup.rb** at line at 192:

```
local_hosts << ic.external_ip << ' ' << hosts_data.compact.join(' ') << "\n"
```

After attempting to debug this with binding.pry, the line 192 goes through without any error.

Any ideas are welcome.

I have also tried:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

as per [Rails 4 Error with every command "`load': no implicit conversion of nil into String" (Mac OS X 10.9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960417/rails-4-error-with-every-command-load-no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-str)